# Почему не работает regex в hasNext()

Tags: java

Мне нужно удалить слова с заданной длиной и чтобы начинались с согласной буквы, сделал через pattern и macher, кажется работает, но почему-то через Scanner не хочет.

```java
File file = new File("src/text.txt");
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        if(!sc.hasNext(String.format("(^[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z])([a-zA-Z]){%s}[,. !]*$", length - 1))) {
            result.append(sc.next()).append(" ");
        }
    }
    sc.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File " + file.getName() + " not found");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: "Мне нужно удалить слова". ^ и $ соответсвуют началу и концу строки. ""...{%s}[,. !]*$", length -  1". %s ожидает строку, а вы передаете число

Comment: разве не любой тип можно давать? %s - any type

Comment: Ну, s - string. А для чисел %d. Там разве idea не подчеркивает? Может, это и так

Comment: я только что проверил так тоже выводит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через сканер не хочет работать потому что возникает бесконечный цикл из-за того, что не пропускается "неподходящая" строка.

Кроме того, как отмечено в комментариях, регулярное выражение не вполне корректно проверяет на совпадение целую строку, то есть в одной строке не может быть более одного слова.

Его можно слегка исправить:

```
String.format("(?i)[B-Z&&[^EIOU]]([A-Z]){%s}[\\s\\p{Punct}]?", length - 1))
```

- `(?i)` - не учитывать регистр при сравнении
- `[B-Z&&[^EIOU]]` - сокращенная форма для всех согласных букв в латинице
- `[\\s\\p{Punct}]?` - после слова может опционально идти пробел или знак пунктуации

Также следует использовать `try-with-resources`, чтобы сканер закрывался автоматически.

Исправленный пример:

```java
String data = "One two three four! Let's run, foo, moo and boo: loo";

int length = 3;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(data)) {
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        if(!sc.hasNext(String.format("(?i)[B-Z&&[^EIOU]]([A-Z]){%s}[\\s\\p{Punct}]?", length - 1))) {
            result.append(sc.next()).append(" ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Skipping: " + sc.next());
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Вывод:

```
Skipping: two
Skipping: run,
Skipping: foo,
Skipping: moo
Skipping: boo:
Skipping: loo
One three four! Let's and
```

Comment: странно почему с pattern работает а через  scanner не работает

Comment: Сканер должен "пропустить" некорректное слово, до тех пор `hasNext()` всегда будет возвращать true.  Как использовали `Pattern` и `Matcher`?

Comment: проверял через regex101 все работает,чего hasNext() не хочет

Comment: @vasilpetrovich можете поставить ссылку на regex101 в вопросе

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/4eH2S9/1

Comment: Что именно у вас не работает?? Какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: То есть вы смотрите на мой пример, в котором вроде бы явно указано, что слова длиной 3 символа, начинающиеся на согласную букву (two, run и т.д.), **отфильтрованы** из результирующей строки - и говорите, что hasNext() не работает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131356/discussion-between-alex-rudenko-and-vasilpetrovich).